# Web Service Call Return

Tags: php, web-services, soap, request, response

I am testing out the performance of different Web Service calls and was wondering how I can specify which fields are returned in the response. I'm thinking that if I query only certain fields, less information will be returned, therefore the response time will be faster. How can I accomplish that in this type of format?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:ns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:com="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RetrieveChangeTaskListRequest>
         <ns:model>

        <ns:keys query="AssignedTo = &quot;drake&quot; and planned.start &gt; '03/01/2016' and planned.start &lt; tod()" ></ns:keys>
        <ns:instance></ns:instance>

     </ns:model>
  </ns:RetrieveChangeTaskListRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking with SOAP, as it returns full objects with all fields intact.

However if you want to shrink the payload size, you can try enabling gzip compression, and if the web server supports it, you will get a nice tiny response.  Instantiate the soapclient like:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($uri, array(
  'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1,
  'trace' => 1,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP
  )
);
```

And then you can check the headers to see if the response was compressed by doing `$soapclient->__getLastRequestHeaders()` for the request, and `$soapclient->__getLastResponseHeaders()` for the response.

In the request header you should see: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` and the response header: `Content-Encoding: gzip` and also `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and you know it worked.